# Can I connect ESP32 via VSCode by connecting via REPL via USB just like Atom does?

Tags: visual-studio-code, usb, esp32

I'm trying to use VSCode to debug MicroPython code running on the ESP32 microcomputer.  VSCode has a "ESP32 debug" plugin which I hope to use to connect my Mac running VSCode via the USB to the ESP32.

This plugin appears not to allow me to specify the tty name to VSCode to establish a REPL like connection to my ESP32 just like Atom does.

Is this plugin the one I should use,  or am I confused as to the purpose of the plugin?

I expected the plugin to prompt me for the USB tty name,  in my case,  this would be /dev/tty.SLAB.USBtoUART which is already installed,  and working on Atom.

I would appreciate any additional info such as additional forums,  or additional plugins I might need.

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Pymakr plugin to connect to the micropython repl and upload/download files, either via serial connection or telnet. It works fine with the esp32. Just configure the port and it should connect.

Comment: Using Pymakr, in order to communicate with my ESP32 Devkit, I had to set the option "auto_connect" to "false". 

This configuration can be found in the Pymakr Global Settings (pymakr.json).